# USB speed 2mb/sec USB (MCU <-->PC) realisation? stm32

Tags: arm, serial-port, usb, stm32

I have the plans to create an emmc reader project where the mcu will read the data chunks (per 8kb) and send it to UI in PC (i guess i will use Visual Studio with serial port implmentation), the problem is that the fast usb speed is required because of emmc mcu has 32gb on board, therefore i need 2mb/sec speed at least. I have stm32h7, VCP is very slow , i can get 450 kb/sec this is the limit due to the package size of 64byte per ms. What other varients? i was thinking about USART (FTDI CHIP) with maximum baud rate, but i doubt i can reach 2mb with it. Also it has to be 2.0 USB , therefore i cant use HighSpeed,  right? becase its only for usb 3.0.
i'm not tied to arm architecture, can use any other chip, any suggestions?

UPD for Codo

```
#define CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE                 64U  /* Endpoint IN & OUT Packet size */
#define CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE                         8U  /* Control Endpoint Packet size */
```

When i change CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE to value more then 64, usb stops working on USB 2.0 HUB, but working on USB 3.0.

Comment: Is "2mb/sec" 2 mega **bytes** per second, or 2 mega **bits** per second?

Comment: There is not such limit as "64byte per ms". Why do you think so?

Comment: @Codo MegaBytes

Comment: @Codo it is in VCP of stm

Comment: @codo and also when i try to increade th eamount of bytes, the usb 2.0 stop working , but working with usb 3,0, so i guess when we want to transfer more then 64bytes we need HighSpeed

Comment: USB full speed goes up to about 12Mbit/s, or 1.5MByte/s (1MByte in practice). So you likely need USB high speed, which is part of USB 2.0. USB 3.0 is not needed. "VCP of stm" does not exist. You probably mean the VCP implementation of STM32Cube. If it stops working when you increase the amount of whatever, you probably have a bug. Why don't you post the code?

Comment: @Codo Please, check the update, i have added the part of the code. Im using HAL library. the code is for FullSpeed, i didnt try HighSpeed, so you say that High speed will work with usb 2.0? The HighSpeed packet size is 512

Comment: For USB full speed, the maximum packet size is indeed 64. But you can increase the FIFO size and submit larger chunks of data at once (for best performance, use multiples of 64). STM32cube will put them into the FIFO and the USB peripheral will send them in packets of 64 bytes, about 10 packets in each 1ms frame. Have a look at `HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo()`.

Comment: @Codo thanks mate, but im willing to look over HS but cant find any examples  HS USB to PC